# Ionic deploy with Injecting Deploy

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I have never used [**Ionic Deploy service**](http://docs.ionic.io/services/deploy/).I would like to use it now.I have a question here.Hope you'll help me.

According to the above doc, I have to do this:

> Import Deploy from the Cloud Client and specify it as a dependency in
>   your component constructor.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Deploy} from '@ionic/cloud-angular';

@Component( ... )
export class MyPage {
  constructor(public deploy: Deploy) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Do I need to this for each and every `page` or where? According to the official doc, it seems `Page`.Can't I use in a single place like `app.componet.ts`? Why do we need to replicate it on each and every `page`?

Comment: Yes. You'll need to inject it where you want to use it.

Comment: Can you give a little bit more about this `where you want to use it`? Can't I use in a single place like `app.componet.ts`? Why do we need to replicate it on each and every page? @iTR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my app I did it on app startup so in app.component.ts i did injection  and then on platform ready checked if there is new update.

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Deploy } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = TabsPage;
  constructor(private platform: Platform,
    public deploy: Deploy) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.checkUpdate();

    });
  }

  checkUpdate() {
    this.deploy
      .check()
      .then((snapshotAvailable: boolean) => {
        if (snapshotAvailable) {
          this.deploy.download().then(() => {
            return this.deploy.extract()
              .then(() => {
                this.deploy.load();
              });
          });
        }
      });
  }
}
```

You can also do it in page if you wish for instance you can add about app page and each time user hit this page you check for new version

Comment: How can I change the `active channel`? Hope your code will work with the `production` channel no?

Comment: @Sampath http://docs.ionic.io/services/deploy/#changing-the-active-channel

Comment: OK.It seems this is a big burden for the app startup no? Hope it courses the performance issues no? Your thoughts?

Comment: @Sampath this is async code so there is not difference in startup ;)

Comment: Yep, Got it. Where we can't use this? I mean when should I go to app store to upgrade process again? Or no need at all it again after the first visit to the app store for a first time publish.

Comment: @Sampath you will need to resubmit to app store only if you added new plugins, which require iOS/Android app rebuild if you changed only ts/js code no need to resubmit this is a benefit of deploy

Comment: One final question though.Can you see any use case where we need to do this on `pages` too? Hope if we do it on `app.compoent.ts` that is more than enough no?

Comment: @Sampath it depends how often you want to check for new version. At some point I would recommend you to return latest version of your app, and to check if header value version is not equal to installed then you can do  version check again. But again it depends so in many cases in app.component should be fine

Comment: OK sure.Thanks :)